# How can I start work on debugging my Python Raycaster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, raycasting

I'm sorry for making the title vague but I honestly have no idea how to describe what its showing.

My code is almost a direct port of the example code on

[www.lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html](http://www.lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html)

My full code is at https://pastebin.com/tK1CNFps

This here is the main part of the program.

```
zde = 0.0000001 #Add to prvent division by zero
res = 2

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 1000

xPos = 10.0
yPos = 5.0
xDir = -1
yDir = 0
xPlane = 0
yPlane = 0.66


for column in range(0,WIDTH,res):
    xCamera = 2 * column / float(WIDTH) - 1.0
    xRayDir = xDir + xPlane * xCamera
    yRayDir = yDir + yPlane * xCamera

    xMap = int(xPos)
    yMap = int(yPos)

    xSideDistance = 0.0
    ySideDistance = 0.0
    perpWallDistance = 0.0

    xDeltaDistance = abs(1/(xRayDir + zde))
    yDeltaDistance = abs(1/(yRayDir + zde))

    xStep = 0
    yStep = 0

    hit = False
    side = 0

    if (xRayDir < 0):
        xStep = -1
        xSideDistance = (xPos - xMap) * xDeltaDistance
    else:
        xStep = -1
        xSideDistance = (xMap + 1.0 - xPos) * xDeltaDistance

    if (xRayDir < 0):
        yStep = -1
        ySideDistance = (yPos - yMap) * yDeltaDistance
    else:
        yStep = 1;
        ySideDistance = (yMap + 1.0 - yPos) * yDeltaDistance

    hit = False
    while not hit:
        if (xSideDistance < ySideDistance):
          xSideDistance += xDeltaDistance
          xMap += xStep
          side = 'x'

        else:
          ySideDistance += yDeltaDistance
          yMap += yStep
          side = 'y'

        if worldMap[xMap][yMap] != 0 :
            hit = True

    if (side == 0):
        perpWallDist = (xMap - xPos + (1 - xStep) / 2) / (xRayDir + zde)
    else:
        perpWallDist = (yMap - yPos + (1 - yStep) / 2) / (yRayDir + zde)

    lineHeight = int(HEIGHT / (perpWallDist + zde))

    drawStart = -lineHeight / 2 + HEIGHT / 2

    if (drawStart < 0):
        drawStart = 0

    drawEnd = lineHeight / 2 + HEIGHT / 2

    if (drawEnd >= HEIGHT):
        drawEnd = HEIGHT - 1

    wallcolours = [ [255,255,255], [150,0,0], [0,150,0], [0,0,150] ]
    colour = wallcolours[worldMap[xMap][yMap]]

    if side == 'y':
        colour = [i/2 for i in colour]

    pygame.draw.line(screen, colour, (column,drawStart), (column, drawEnd), res)
```

Screenshots of mine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6PIh.jpg

Screenshots of a similar, working program: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KHNO.jpg

Any help or advice is welcome, because I don't even know where I would start here.

Comment: How about "how to start debugging"? That would describe what your title says but with less words. Please rework your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: take a close look at xStep if xRayDir >= 0, I think there is a mistake there, at least it is different from what you do with yStep.

Comment: Your `side` variable seems to be getting values either the literal character `x` or `y`, and yet you're testing `if (side == 0):`. I didn't check the full code, but I think there's something fishy there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found these three mistakes (the commented lines). The game should work correctly if you fix these issues.

```
if xRayDir < 0:
    xStep = -1
    xSideDistance = (xPos - xMap) * xDeltaDistance
else:
    xStep = 1  # Set xStep to 1 not -1.
    xSideDistance = (xMap + 1.0 - xPos) * xDeltaDistance

if yRayDir < 0:  # xRayDir changed to yRayDir.
    yStep = -1
    ySideDistance = (yPos - yMap) * yDeltaDistance
else:
    yStep = 1;
    ySideDistance = (yMap + 1.0 - yPos) * yDeltaDistance
```

---

```
if side == 'x':  # 0 changed to 'x'. You set `side` to 'x' or 'y' earlier.
    perpWallDist = (xMap - xPos + (1 - xStep) / 2) / (xRayDir + zde)
else:
    perpWallDist = (yMap - yPos + (1 - yStep) / 2) / (yRayDir + zde)
```

Comment: I've just compared your code with the original C++ code to find these bugs, but if you don't have this luxury, you need to use a debugger or print the variables and compare them to the expected values.